# Auto fill additional sheets from a main sheet in Excel 2010

Tags: excel

In Excel 2010, I want to create a workbook with a number of sheets, sheet 1 will be my data entry page, name, address, city, state, zip, phone number, note 1, note 2, note 3, note 4, note 5. I want some of the specified info to then populate on the other sheets. Not all sheets will use all the info, and the info will be placed in different rows and cells than from sheet 1 the data sheet. The info will be duplicated, no change from what is entered in sheet 1.

Answer (score 2):

Well

You could try to use a macro, if you are trying to fill the other worksheets filter by the sheet name, you could use something like this:

```
Sub Filter_info()

Dim i As Integer, iLR As Integer
Dim sName As String, sSName() As String
Dim vSName As Variant
Dim Wkb As Workbook, Wks As Worksheet, WksC As Worksheet

Set Wkb = Workbooks("workbook_name")
Set Wks = Wkb.Worksheets("shee1_Name")

x = 0 
'' create Worksheets list
For Each vSName In Worksheets

    sName = vSName.Name
    ReDim Preserve sSName(x)
    sSName(x) = sName

    x = x + 1
Next

iLR = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 0 To UBound(sSName)

    Set WksC = Wkb.Worksheets(sSName(i))
    y = 1

    For j = 1 To iLR

    '' Here you can decide with which cell you are going to compare
        If sSName(i) = Wks.Range("A1") Then
            Wks.Range("A1").Copy WksC.Cells(y, 1)
            y = y + 1
        End If

    Next j

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My example code assumes Sheet1!A1 is the cell you want to copy. All you would need to do is type

```
=Sheet1!A1
```

to the destination cells